# OS X network routing issue trying to use 2 interfaces

Tags: networking, macos, mac, osx-yosemite, osx-mavericks

I am having issues with routing on my Mac(OS X Mojave), I have two network interfaces set up on separate networks, 12.20.10.191 for en0 and 170.16.20.69 for en1.  I have set up routing using route -add to the gateway for the second interface en1 to 170.16.20.254.

Here is where it gets interesting for me. With both interfaces connected I can only reach addresses on en0 when I try to ping or get to an address on en1 everything fails.  However when I either disconnect the network cable from en0 or change the service order to put en1 higher than en0 I can then ping and access addresses routed through en1 but can no longer communicate with addresses on en0.  I am not sure what I am missing in getting both interfaces to work at the same time but any ideas what I can do to resolve the issue are appreciated.

#### Adding routing table

##### Routing tables

```
Internet:
Destination        Gateway            Flags        Refs      Use   Netif Expire
default            12.20.10.191       UGSc          116        0     en0       
default            170.16.20.254      UGScI           0        0     en1       
127                127.0.0.1          UCS             0        0     lo0       
127.0.0.1          127.0.0.1          UH              1      326     lo0       
12.20.10/24        link#7             UCS            27        0     en0      
12.20.10.191/32    link#7             UCS             0        0     en0      
12.20.10.254/32    link#7             UCS             1        0     en0      !
169.254            link#7             UCS             2        0     en0      !
169.254            link#8             UCSI            0        0     en1      !
170.16.20/24       link#8             UCS             2        0     en1      !
170.16.20.69/32    link#8             UCS             1        0     en1      !
170.16.20.254/32   link#8             UCS             1        0     en1      !
224.0.0/4          link#7             UmCS            1        0     en0      !
224.0.0/4          link#8             UmCSI           1        0     en1      !
255.255.255.255/32 link#7             UCS             0        0     en0      !
255.255.255.255/32 link#8             UCSI            0        0     en1      !
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the setup & requirements correctly. Do you have both interfaces (and their IPs and subnets etc) set up as network "services" in System Preferences -> Network pane? If so, what exactly is the additional route you're adding with the `route` command? Finally, when you talk about reaching addresses "on en0" or "on en1", are you talking about addresses on the same subnet as your interface, or something else (and if so, what)? Adding the output of `netstat -rn -finet` would help also (although you might want to censor the lines with a MAC address as the "gateway").

Comment: I added the routing table to the original question.  On the network pane I have "Ethernet 1" and "Ethernet 2".  For the ethernet 2 I ran the following command to add an additional route.  sudo route add -host 170.16.20.254 -interface en1  and  sudo route -n add -net 170.16.0.0/12 170.16.20.254